# How to configure iptables to forward all traffic to another host, but let said other host see the real IPs of clients?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a server (server a) with a public IP, and another server (server b) which is behind a NAT. I would like server a to pass all traffic (TCP, UDP, ICMP, etc) to server b, so that a client connecting to server a will be transparently forwarded to server b. I am using iptables for this as that's what I am most comfortable in. So far I have this setup working with a DNAT rule and a MASQUERADE rule, but the glaring issue is that every log on server b shows server a's IP as the IP of every client. Is there any way to fix this? My thought was if NAT routers can do this when you forward ports, it must somehow be possible on Linux.

Also, I have tried DMZing server b, but for reasons way out of this question's scope that setup no longer works, I just need a real dedicated public IP.

Comment: Don't MASQUERADE, add "return routes" for the "replying" traffics on hosts where the "original" traffics go to. If you can't cover all possible destinations (of the replies) for any reason, you might need/want to resort to policy routing (assuming those hosts have support for such thing.)

Comment: See this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712838/how-to-forward-packets-with-keeping-the-original-ip-address).

Comment: If server A is not server B's gateway, or is not in the path for server B's Internet traffic, then you must use a tunnel to carry such traffic over actual Internet (along whatever other way to put traffic in this tunnel). iptables alone won't do it, and if you have a tunnel, iptables is not needed anymore. So on a schematic where are server A, server B its NAT router and the client along the rest of Internet?

Comment: @A.B server A is directly attached to a WAN connection, server B is on a LAN behind a NAT, but has a reliable way to access other hosts and for other hosts to access it (that is, no symmetric NAT or anything similar). There is a point to point tunnel between the two on which there is a non-globally routable (198.18.0.0/15) address on each end. I think I see why the tunnel is needed while I'm writing this. My original assumption was if server A forwarded a request to server B over the internet, it would use the IP of server A to reply, but it makes sense why not.

Comment: Though even if I do apply the rules over the tunnel, my only working option still seems to only be a MASQUERADE rule which doesn't show the real IP of clients to server B.

Comment: And @harrymc that post also makes sense, it seems like iptables with SNAT/DNAT rules doesn't have an option to keep the clients' IPs. Which I guess makes sense. Do you know if any software can do this? If so I'll look into a better option.

Comment: Sorry, software recommendations are off-subject on this site.

Comment: DNAT does not modify the source address of the redirected traffics. SNAT/MASQUERADE does, and that's their very nature/purpose, so it doesn't even make sense to say "they don't have option to keep the original address". All the WAN/LAN/behind NAT you mentioned seem to be irrelevant here, since apparently the forwarding / redirection of traffics makes use of a tunnel, i.e., A and B are "directly" reachable to each other in the "logical" sense / context of concern, which means you don't *have to* apply source NAT on the traffics A is redirecting, since you can make B use it as *the* gateway.

Comment: "*The* gateway" can be "*a* default gateway" if necessary. It doesn't have to be "*the only/main* default gateway though. At least on Linux, you can "split tunnel" with policy routing (ip rule, with the help of ct mark and mark if necessary).

Comment: @harrymc I was more implying a more broad "is it possible", I didn't want to ask anyone on here to help me find software because I shouldn't push that onto others. But I assume it is possible somehow, so I'll take a look.

Comment: @TomYan That makes sense, thank you very much. Correct me if I'm wrong, but could I just use (for example) NetworkManager to set the originating tunnel IP as the gateway for that interface, and then use that as a route for those packets only, without a default route? I am seeing this as at least moderately possible and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but you don't really need a gateway on a point to point tunnel since it's inheritly, always the other end/point of the tunnel. Whether you need a default route depends on what are the possible source IPs. If A is redirecting for "clients" from the Internet, then you'll need a default route. If it's just some other private network A is connected to, then you don't need a default route. "default" really just means `0.0.0.0/0` (all v4 IPs). And whether you need policy routing depends on whether this new route you need conflict with any existing one on the system.

Comment: @TomYan Fair point about the gateway VS default route. My idea was to only use the tunnel for connections that came through it in the first place (continue using server B's NAT gateway for other connections), which I _think_ I can use iptables on server B with a "mark" rule for? I now see that server A alone cannot handle the routing for this. Knowing server B needs to be involved definitely helps me try to troubleshoot things myself.

Comment: I'm also going to look into policy routing which I am now remembering from earlier comments

Comment: @RobertL. mark rule is a component of one of the policy routing approaches. The idea is to label "connections" with "ct mark", which allows you to match replies that belong to the marked connections with "(fw)mark", which is in turn one of the ways to match traffics in an ip rule.

Comment: I'm still a little confused, you mentioned that DNAT doesn't modify source address, but iptables seems to be doing that anyways, as if I ping server A it goes across the tunnel to server B where the source IP is the tunnel IP of server A. Server B is in fact responding across the tunnel, but the IP of the device initiating the ping doesn't seem to be known to server B.

Comment: Ah, I had the MASQUERADE rule too, intended for traffic going the other way, but it was affecting the traffic going out on the tunnel interface too. But removing this rule or specifying "-o eth0" in the rule prevents traffic from reaching the other server at all...